# Using JavaScript to populate a select's options as well remove them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a page that allows a user to assign players to positions. I have an array of player names, and an array of positions that any player can play. Each player is able to play any position in any of the 4 quarters. However, in the same quarter, two players cannot play the same position.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to remove a position from the select options once it has been assigned to another player that quarter(and add a position back to the list if it had been selected then deselected.)

Here is my Javascript that creates a table. Each row has a player's name and a select option for each of the 4 quarters.

```
 //Creates an array of players
 var aRoster = ["Phil", "Erik", "Dave", "Jimbo", "Billy Ray", "Sean", "Joe", "PP", "Shelly", "Mathew", "Scott", "Jarvis", "Hazard", "Ibra"]; 
 //Creates an array of positions players can play
 var aPositions = ["--", "LF", "RF", "LM", "LCM", "RCM", "RM", "CB", "LB", "SW", "RB", "K"];
var htmlStr = "<table class='table-bordered'><thread><tr><th class='col-xs-4'>Name</th><th class='col-xs-2'>Q1</th><th class='col-xs-2'>Q2</th><th class='col-xs-2'>Q3</th><th class='col-xs-2'>Q4</th></tr></thread><tbody>";

//Goes through a loop that puts each player in the table. Gives them an unique selector for each of the 4 quarters 
for(var i=0; i < aRoster.length; ++i) 
{

    htmlStr += "<tr>";
    htmlStr += "<td>" + aRoster[i] + "</td>";
    htmlStr += "<td>" + "<select id=" + "'" + i +"positionQ1' class='form-control'></select>" + "</td>";
    htmlStr += "<td>" + "<select id=" + "'" + i +"positionQ2' class='form-control'></select>" + "</td>";
    htmlStr += "<td>" + "<select id=" + "'" + i +"positionQ3' class='form-control'></select>" + "</td>";
    htmlStr += "<td>" + "<select id=" + "'" + i +"positionQ4' class='form-control'></select>" + "</td>";
    htmlStr += "</tr>";
}
htmlStr += "</tbody></table>";
$('#roster-table').html(htmlStr);

//For each of the player's selectors, populate it with each positon
for (var i = 0; i < aRoster.length; i++) 
{
    var selectQ1 = document.getElementById( i+'positionQ1' );
    var selectQ2 = document.getElementById( i+'positionQ2' );
    var selectQ3 = document.getElementById( i+'positionQ3' );
    var selectQ4 = document.getElementById( i+'positionQ4' );
    for (var j = 0; j < aPositions.length; j++) 
    {
        selectQ1.options.add(new Option(aPositions[j], aPositions[j]));
        selectQ2.options.add(new Option(aPositions[j], aPositions[j]));
        selectQ3.options.add(new Option(aPositions[j], aPositions[j]));
        selectQ4.options.add(new Option(aPositions[j], aPositions[j]));
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Let's say in Quarter 1, Phil has been assigned with position "LF". Are you expecting that "LF" should be removed from all other select controls in the Quarter 1?

Comment: Correct. If Phil is the LF for Q1 then LF should be eliminated from the rest of the player's select options for Q1. But in Q2 anyone is able to play LF, until LF is selected in Q2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

**Steps:**

- Add a class (let's say "q-1") for select controls in each quarter.
  This is done to handle the change event of select controls in each
  quarter
- Create a method called 'PopulatePositions' which always clears any existing values in the select controls and populate with new values. This is done to refresh the select controls during change event.
- Handle the change event of select controls in each quarter and hookup with the common method called 'HandleSelection' (logic is simple. see the method)

```js
//Creates an array of players
 var aRoster = ["Phil", "Erik", "Dave", "Jimbo", "Billy Ray", "Sean", "Joe", "PP", "Shelly", "Mathew", "Scott", "Jarvis", "Hazard", "Ibra"]; 
 //Creates an array of positions players can play
 var aPositions = ["--", "LF", "RF", "LM", "LCM", "RCM", "RM", "CB", "LB", "SW", "RB", "K"];
var htmlStr = "<table class='table-bordered'><thread><tr><th class='col-xs-4'>Name</th><th class='col-xs-2'>Q1</th><th class='col-xs-2'>Q2</th><th class='col-xs-2'>Q3</th><th class='col-xs-2'>Q4</th></tr></thread><tbody>";

//Goes through a loop that puts each player in the table. Gives them an unique selector for each of the 4 quarters 
for(var i=0; i < aRoster.length; ++i) 
{

    htmlStr += "<tr>";
    htmlStr += "<td>" + aRoster[i] + "</td>";
    htmlStr += "<td>" + "<select id=" + "'" + i +"positionQ1' class='form-control q-1'></select>" + "</td>";
    htmlStr += "<td>" + "<select id=" + "'" + i +"positionQ2' class='form-control q-2'></select>" + "</td>";
    htmlStr += "<td>" + "<select id=" + "'" + i +"positionQ3' class='form-control q-3'></select>" + "</td>";
    htmlStr += "<td>" + "<select id=" + "'" + i +"positionQ4' class='form-control q-4'></select>" + "</td>";
    htmlStr += "</tr>";
}
htmlStr += "</tbody></table>";
$('#roster-table').html(htmlStr);

//For each of the player's selectors, populate it with each positon
PopulateQ1Positions();
PopulateQ2Positions();
PopulateQ3Positions();
PopulateQ4Positions();


function PopulateQ1Positions(retainSelection)
{
  for (var i = 0; i < aRoster.length; i++) 
  {
    var selectQ1 = document.getElementById( i+'positionQ1' );  
    
    var currentSelectedValue = $(selectQ1).val();
  
    $(selectQ1).empty();   
  
    for (var j = 0; j < aPositions.length; j++) 
    {
        selectQ1.options.add(new Option(aPositions[j], aPositions[j]));       
    }
    
    if (retainSelection==true)
      {    
        $(selectQ1).val(currentSelectedValue);
      }
  }  
}

function PopulateQ2Positions(retainSelection)
{
  for (var i = 0; i < aRoster.length; i++) 
  {
    var selectQ2 = document.getElementById( i+'positionQ2' ); 
    
    var currentSelectedValue = $(selectQ2).val();
  
    $(selectQ2).empty();   
  
    for (var j = 0; j < aPositions.length; j++) 
    {
        selectQ2.options.add(new Option(aPositions[j], aPositions[j]));       
    }
    
    if (retainSelection==true)
      {    
        $(selectQ2).val(currentSelectedValue);
      }
  }  
}

function PopulateQ3Positions(retainSelection)
{
  for (var i = 0; i < aRoster.length; i++) 
  {
    var selectQ3 = document.getElementById( i+'positionQ3' );  
    
    var currentSelectedValue = $(selectQ3).val();
  
    $(selectQ3).empty();   
  
    for (var j = 0; j < aPositions.length; j++) 
    {
        selectQ3.options.add(new Option(aPositions[j], aPositions[j]));       
    }
    
    if (retainSelection==true)
      {    
        $(selectQ3).val(currentSelectedValue);
      }
  }  
}

function PopulateQ4Positions(retainSelection)
{
  for (var i = 0; i < aRoster.length; i++) 
  {
    var selectQ4 = document.getElementById( i+'positionQ4' ); 
    
    var currentSelectedValue = $(selectQ4).val();
  
    $(selectQ4).empty();   
  
    for (var j = 0; j < aPositions.length; j++) 
    {
        selectQ4.options.add(new Option(aPositions[j], aPositions[j]));       
    }
    
    if (retainSelection==true)
      {    
        $(selectQ4).val(currentSelectedValue);
      }
  }  
}




//events

var q1SelectCtrl = $('.q-1');
var q2SelectCtrl = $('.q-2');
var q3SelectCtrl = $('.q-3');
var q4SelectCtrl = $('.q-4');


q1SelectCtrl.on('change', function()
  {  
     HandleSelection($(this), 'q1');       
  });


q2SelectCtrl.on('change', function()
  {  
     HandleSelection($(this), 'q2');       
  });


q3SelectCtrl.on('change', function()
  {  
     HandleSelection($(this), 'q3');       
  });

q4SelectCtrl.on('change', function()
  {  
     HandleSelection($(this), 'q4');       
  });

function HandleSelection(thisCtrl, target)
{
     var selectedValue = thisCtrl.val();
     var selectedCtrlId = thisCtrl.attr('id');  
  
     var quarterCtrls = null;
  
     if (target == 'q1')
       {
         quarterCtrls = q1SelectCtrl;
         PopulateQ1Positions(true); //refresh
       }
       else if (target == 'q2')
       {
         quarterCtrls = q2SelectCtrl;
         PopulateQ2Positions(true); //refresh
       }
       else if (target == 'q3')
       {
         quarterCtrls = q3SelectCtrl;
         PopulateQ3Positions(true); //refresh
       }
       else if (target == 'q4')
       {
         quarterCtrls = q4SelectCtrl;
         PopulateQ4Positions(true); //refresh
       }
     
  
     thisCtrl.val(selectedValue);
  
     var qSelectedValueArray = [];
  
     $.each(quarterCtrls, function(ctrlIndex, selectCtrl)
     {
       if ($(selectCtrl).val() != '--')
       {
           var item = {};
           item.Value = $(selectCtrl).val();
           item.ControlId = $(selectCtrl).attr('id');
           
         qSelectedValueArray.push(item);
       }
     });    
   
  
     $.each(quarterCtrls, function(ctrlIndex, selectCtrl)
     {
        $.each(qSelectedValueArray, function(itemIndex, qSelectedValue){
            
            if (qSelectedValue.ControlId != $(selectCtrl).attr('id'))
            {
               $(selectCtrl).find('option[value="'+qSelectedValue.Value+'"]').remove();
            }
        });
       
     });   

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="roster-table"></div>
```

Comment: On my page it is never going into the to the q1SelectCrtl on change functions.  Also on your snippet when you select a new position it sets the re sets the last position you just selected.

Comment: I added $( document ).ready(function()  before the events so it eliminates the last selected position from the options, but it still gets rid of the last player you just assigned a position to.

Comment: Fixed the issue ("select a new position it sets the re sets the last position you just selected"). Please verify now.

Comment: It is slightly fixed. But if you were to select Phil as a 'LF' for **Q1**, and the select Erik as a 'RF' for **Q1**, Phil goes back to '--' .  I believe the issue is that when you call the PopulateQ1Positions (or any of the PopulalteQPositions) function you are setting selectQ1 to empty for every player in that quarter.

Comment: @RYDiiN, let me fix that quickly.

Comment: @RYDiiN, please verify now.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is absolutely perfect.